# ADB backup command sometimes fails

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to create a backup on the Whatsapp data from an Android device, using an older version of the Whatsapp app, in which the tag `allowBackup` is `true`.

I'm using the following command:

```
adb backup -f /Users/user/Desktop/backup.ab -apk com.whatsapp
```

This works in about 50% of the cases -> it creates an .ab file of a 10-100MB, depending on how much data is stored by the app.

In the other 50% of the cases, the .ab file is <1KB in size, and it looks like it does not contain any data from the app.

I have tried this with multiple apps, not only Whatsapp, and having similar results with them.

I'm looking to understand what might cause the creation of invalid backups and how I can make sure that a valid backup is created each time.

Comment: Usually adb works or works not for an specifc app on a device, but that it fails randmo is strange. `adb backup` is just the shortcut for `adb shell bu <parameters>`. If you execute the bu command o the phone you may get an error message that may explain the error in case it fails. Also check logging of your system if the USB device disapperas and reappears (is unstable e.g. because of a bad cable).